# putting DICOM files into a repository

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository, dicom

Firstly im new to the concept of a repository so pardon me if my question is not apt or complete. I have a set of DICOM files, which i have to put in a repository. I should be able to add/remove/modify the contents of the repository and this change should be noted soon (like a listener). I should also be able to parse through the repository. I looked at LINQ to SQL, but i'm not sure if it satisfies all the things i said above. Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The fun part is that DICOM messages/files can be quite large. So large that one might be hesitant to drop the files as a BLOB into a SQL DB. If that is the case,

1. Extract some features from the DICOM file, let's call them A, B, C, ...
2. Create a DB table with columns A, B, C, ... <*filename*>
3. Store the DICOM file on the disk under <*filename*>
4. Implement access to the DICOM file accordingly

If you're using Linq to talk to the DB, you can now use all goodies that Linq has to offer, and you won't be lugging around the full DICOM files all the time, making access to the table rather light-weight.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're really looking for here.  If you're looking for a DICOM-specific solution, you might want a [PACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_archiving_and_communication_system) of some sort or some other server providing a appropriate DICOM storage [SCP](http://www.scribd.com/doc/13146/About-SCU-and-SCP) (service class provider).  But if you're just looking for somewhere to save files with versioning and a log, just check them into [svn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion).

Comment: Hey Timday,thanks for the suggestion! I was also looking at the Oracle 11g database, as i think it parses the DICOM files.I was looking at it at http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/11g/r1/prod/datamgmt/dicom/dicom.htm Im not sure if i could use it to query in c# (i'm a beginner,not much of an idea). Would you happen to know if i could?

Comment: Hmmm interesting; that looks like a very nice feature!  Sorry don't know more than that but it certainly looks potentially useful.